# PhpStorm 8 Live Edit and Chrome Extension don't update external CSS

Tags: google-chrome, phpstorm, liveedit

After googling for answers and trying everything that was suggested, I still can't resolve this issue.

What I tried:

- Downloaded/installed/enabled Live Edit plugin
- Configured a JavaScript Debug configuration
- Changed `Update to Auto in (ms)` and checked `Restart if hotswap fails`
- Specified the same port I use in JetBrains IDE Support in Debugger and checked `Can accept external connections`
- Tried Updating Application (CTRL+F10)

Now the thing is, after I save the CSS file and open the Development tools panel in Chrome, **I can see the change applied in Styles tab, but the browser doesn't render it**. I tried checking `Enable continuous page repainting`, but it didn't change anything.

HTML, PHP and inline CSS changes do update.

Software versions:

- PhpStorm 8.0.3
- Chrome 42.0.2311.135
- JetBrains IDE Support 2.0.8

Comment: Have a look -- maybe it's your case as well? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12926

Comment: @LazyOne, looks like it, so the update from jetbrains should fix that.